# Calculating function and writing output number by number as an array

Tags: c++, c, math, numbers

So, what I basically need is to calculate value of an exponential function *(2^n)*(2^(n-1)-1)* using c++, where n is a unsigned int type user input. Since n can be assigned any value in unsigned int range, I cannot simply calculate function value and assign it to some unsigned int variable (because resulting number will clearly be out of said range). Therefore, it seems reasonable to me to somehow get my desired function value number by number and write each number as a array element. The only struggle is to realise this method.

Any ideas (both using proposed method or any other one) would be much appreciated.

edit:
Right now I have the following code:

```cpp
outdated
```

As expected, it will only work with small values of n

Edit 2: as one of the commentators suggested, I've done some binary numbers by hand. It was pretty fruitful, but I still need sime assistance. Now i have the following code, which will correctly output binary value of said function:

```
outdated
```

The only thing left is to convert this value to decimal and hexadecimal. I am not experienced at working with string class, so advice would be appreciated.

Edit 3: Thanks everyone for help. I've completed my program and converted it co C (not willingly, because my professor told me to do so). For anyone interested, the current version of code looks like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void binary(unsigned int);
void hex(unsigned int);
void decimal(unsigned int);
int *calculatepower(unsigned int, unsigned int);
void addition(int*, int*, int);

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    if (argc != 2){
        printf("wrong number of arguments \n");
        return -2;
    }
    unsigned int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("exponent - %d \n", n);
    binary(n);
    hex(n);
    decimal(n);
    return 0;
}

void binary(unsigned int n){
    int i;
    printf("binary - ");
    for (i=n-1; i>0; i--)
        printf("1");
    for (i=n; i>0; i--)
        printf("0");
    printf("\n");
}

void hex(unsigned int nn){
    int ones = nn-1;
    int zeroes = nn;
    int hexzeroes=0, hexfs=0, i;
    char switchf, switchzero;
    while (zeroes > 3){
        hexzeroes+=1;
        zeroes-=4;
    }
    switch (zeroes){
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            switchzero='E';
        ones-=3;
        break;
        case 2:
            switchzero='C';
        ones-=2;
        break;
        case 3:
            switchzero='8';
        ones-=1;
        break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    while (ones>3){
        hexfs+=1;
        ones-=4;
    }
    switch (ones){
        case 0:
            switchf='\0';
            break;
        case 1:
            switchf='1';
            break;
        case 2:
            switchf='3';
            break;
        case 3:
            switchf='7';
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    printf("hexadecimal - %c", switchf);
    for (i=0; i<hexfs; i++)
        printf("F");
    if (zeroes !=0) printf("%c", switchzero);
    for (i=0; i<hexzeroes; i++)
        printf("0");
    printf("\n");
}

void decimal(unsigned int nn){
    unsigned int n=nn;
    int *str,*powerstr, i, flag=0;
    // decimal = 2^n+...+2^((2*n)-1)
    unsigned int size = (2*n)/3 + 2;
    str = (int*)calloc(size, sizeof(*str));
    if(str==NULL)
    {
        printf("unable to allocate memory");
        exit(0);
    }
    for (i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        str[i] = 0;
    }
    for (n;n<2*nn-1;n++){
        powerstr = calculatepower( n, size);
        addition(str,powerstr,size);
   }
    printf("decimal - ");
    for (i=0;i<size;i++) {
        if ((*(str+i)==0) && (flag==0)){
            continue;
        }
        printf("%d", *(str+i));
        flag+=1;
    }
}

int *calculatepower(unsigned int n, unsigned int size){
    int i, j, buf=0, *powerstr;
    powerstr = (int*)calloc(size, sizeof(*powerstr));
    for (i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        powerstr[i] = 0;
    }
    powerstr[size-1]=1;
    for(j=0;j<n;j++) {
        for (i=size-1; i > -1; i--) {
            powerstr[i] = powerstr[i] * 2;
            if (buf!=0) {
                powerstr[i] += 1;
                buf=0;
            }
            if (powerstr[i] > 9) {
                buf = 1;
                powerstr[i]%=10;
            }

        }
    }
    return powerstr;
}

void addition(int *str, int *powerstr, int size){
    int i, buf=0;
    for (i=size-1; i > -1; i--) {
        str[i] = powerstr[i] + str[i];
        if (buf!=0) {
            str[i] += 1;
            buf=0;
        }
        if (str[i] > 9) {
            buf = 1;
            str[i]%=10;
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I do not have enough time to polish it. The current biggest problem is not freeing allocated memory and I will fix it later, but I won't update queastion anymore. Thanks again everyone for your answers and comments.

Comment: Are you sure you need to calculate this number? If this is some coding competition I expect the answer is no.

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure. The task sounds like the following: "Develop a programm that calculates function (2^n)*(2^(n-1)-1) with any integer value of exponent n > 1, that is allowed in unsigned int range of c++ programming language"

Comment: Actually very simple. Just a few lines of code. Obvious if you know binary. Try some numbers by hand and you will see the simple pattern. Oh, and by hand I mean in binary by hand.

Comment: It would be better if you show what you have tried so far. Post code, not only explanations.

Comment: You can use `unsigned long`, `unsigned long long`, or `uint64_t` (or the maximum value if 64 is not supported).

Comment: Usually, you can replace `pow(2, n)` with a left shift: `(1 << n)`.  The left shift is usually one or two instructions vs. a whole bunch of instructions to call, execute and return from the `pow` function.  This is for integral numbers.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews This is very fast code. But the out-of-range problem is still persistent.

Comment: Cool, you see the pattern. But did you calculate how many digits, decimal or otherwise, are in 4294967295^2? Looks like it takes to the end of the universe at 1000/sec to output the values. 16 bit unsigned ints, possible to calculate in a second or two, but still very long. 32 bits? Not so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 16 bit ints it's doable and produces about 40k decimal chars. For 32 bit ints, not so much as it's about 10^20 decimal chars which is beyond anything possible. Even outputting a million chars per second would take longer than the lifetime of the universe.

Here's code for 16 bit ints. Runs in about 3 seconds for n = 65535 not including output time. It has performance improvements by accumulating base 10 sums and normalizing occasionally to prevent overflow.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
using std::cout;
using std::vector;
using std::string;

struct BigDecPower2 {
    static constexpr uint32_t Normalize_Max{ 26 };        // int8:3, int16:10, int32:26
    vector<uint32_t> v;
    uint32_t top;
    uint32_t normalize_count;
    BigDecPower2(uint32_t n) : v(n), top(0), normalize_count(0) {};
    void normalize()
    {
        normalize_count = 0;
        for (uint32_t i = 0;; i++)
        {
            v[i + 1] += v[i] / 10u;
            v[i] = v[i] % 10u;
            if (i >= top && v[i + 1] == 0)
            {
                top = i;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    void times2() {
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i <= top; i++)
            v[i] *= 2;
        if ((++normalize_count) > Normalize_Max)
            normalize();
    }
};

void add(BigDecPower2& v1, const BigDecPower2& v2)
{
    uint32_t max_top = v1.top > v2.top ? v1.top : v2.top;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i <= max_top; i++)
        v1.v[i] += v2.v[i];
    if (++v1.normalize_count < v2.normalize_count)
        v1.normalize_count = v2.normalize_count;
    if (v1.normalize_count > v1.Normalize_Max)
        v1.normalize();
}

void print_base(unsigned int n, int number_base)
{
    int64_t ones = n-1;
    int64_t zeros = n;
    if (number_base ==2)
    {
        while (ones-- > 0)
            cout << '1';
        while (zeros-- > 0)
            cout << '0';
    }
    else if (number_base == 16) {
        int resid = (ones + zeros) % 4;
        if (resid == 0)
            resid = 4;
        cout << "~137F"[resid];
        ones -= resid;
        while ((ones -= 4) > 0)
            cout << 'F';
        cout << "8CEF"[ones + 3];
        zeros /= 4;
        while (zeros--)
            cout << '0';
    }
    else if (number_base == 10)
    {
        BigDecPower2 v_accum(40000u);
        BigDecPower2 v_pwr(40000u); v_pwr.v[0] = 1;
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            add(v_accum, v_pwr);
            v_pwr.times2();
        }
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
            v_accum.times2();
        v_accum.normalize();
        for (uint32_t i = v_accum.top; i != -1; i--)
            cout << static_cast<char>(v_accum.v[i] + '0');
    }
    cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    //    calcs in about 3 seconds, outputs about 40k decimal chars
    //    print_base(0xffff, 10);
    // Demo
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        print_base(i, 2);
        print_base(i, 16);
        print_base(i, 10);
        cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long` (or `uintX_t` where `X` is the maximum supported size on your platform) if `unsigned int` cannot hold your output. If that's still not enough for your use case, then either implement your own big integer class, or use an existing library (recommended if you can afford it). There are a couple of them out there. For example, [GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library (GMP)](https://gmplib.org/) and [bigint-library](https://github.com/square1001/bigint-library). See [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_C%2B%2B_multiple_precision_arithmetic_libraries) for more.

---

In case you decided to go on your own and implement your own class, this might give you some clues on how to start. (Note that, for efficiency matters, number theory algorithms may be applied. It is not an easy task to come with a good implementation).

```cpp
template<typename T = unsigned, int Base = 10> class Bigint {
    std::vector<T> digits;
    bool sign; // For e.g. true for + or 0, false for -

public:
    Bigint() : digits(), sign(true) { }
    
    Bigint(int x)
    {
        // Insert digits of x into digits vector
        // Don't forget the sign
    }
    // Do the same with other types: short, long, unsigned, etc.
    
    Bigint(const char *x)
    {
        // You need to parse x. Bad formatting is to be handled (tip: use exceptions)
    }
    // Provide an std::string version
    
    Bigint(const Bigint& bi) : digits(bi.digits), sign(bi.sign) {}

    Bigint& operator=(const Bigint& bi)
    {
        // Copy...
        return *this;
    }
    
    // You also have to implement operators
    Bigint& operator+(const Bigint& bi)
    {
        // Logic...
        return *this;
    }
    // Other operators: -, /, %, bitwise, etc.
    // Tip: you can use a helper class to be used by both / and % since they share a similar logic (for avoiding redundant code).
    
    Bigint power(const Bigint& bi) // Provide other signatures: int, string, etc.
    {
        // Logic...
    }
};
```